# Problems with object orientation and angled array

Tags: modifiers, transform-orientation

[image]
I need my glass panels to stick to the metal frame of my building. The axes are set to global and I've tried CTRL+A and CTRL + ALT + SPACE but nothing works.

[image]

I need my Y arrow to be perpendicular with the object and the X arrow parallel so that the glass panels array in a straight line without having to change other values in the relative offset setting

Comment: attach your file here http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?ref=be-community-add-2 for detail inspection

Comment: Only need one offset in array modifier, and align the object.  Have you altered the plane (panel glass) mesh in edit mode so that it is no longer on axis plane.  Default plane is on xy (z=0) plane for instance.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

1. Select two vertices,
2. Change Transformation Orientations to Normal,
3. Press the add button in the Transform Orientations panel then
4. Select new normal, ie Edge, in the drop down list.

[image]

5. In Object mode, shift+S > Cursor to selected,
6. Shift+A  > Empty > Plane Axes,
7. Set the constraint as shown in the figure and
8. Move Empty object using added normal(Edge).

Comment: The orientation is set but the array of glass panels still wont form a straight line.

Comment: I wrote a continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Add Array Modifier
Set the count
Tick mark Relative Offset & Constant Offset

Adjust the Relative Offset for the gaps

Adjust the Constant Offset for the height and alignment

**Here is the example below**

[image]

Comment: If the answer is useful press the tick mark to confirm answer